# PHP - Check if all the elements of an array are in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array, `$my_array`, containing `n` element and a string, `$my_string`. I want to check if ALL the elements of `$my_array` are in `$my_string`. The order in which they are found in the string is not important as long as they are all there. I'm looking for the most efficient solution to get a `TRUE` only if all of the elements are present.

**TRUE:**

```
$my_array = array("big", "blue", "sky", "dog"); 
$my_string = "my big dog loves the blue sky";
```

**FALSE:**

```
$my_array = array("big", "blue", "sky", "dog"); 
$my_string = "the big blue sky";
```

Comment: What about The Blue Dog?

Comment: I could do it in a loop, I just wanted to know if there is a built in function in php to do so

Comment: I'd say that a loop works best.

Comment: @LaGuille: You can try `array_diff` or `array_intersect`, if you do something like `explode(' ', $my_string)`.

Comment: Do you want exact words, with punctuation included?  As i pointed out it makes a difference ( pun intended ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, don't be afraid of arrays.

```
  $my_array = array("big", "blue", "sky", "dog");
  $my_string = "my big dog loves the blue sky"

  function arrayInString( array $my_array, $my_string ){
    $my_string = explode(' ', $my_string);
    // difference return all elements of array one not in array two
    $diff = array_diff($my_array, $my_string);
    if(empty( $diff )){
        //if there is no difference there are no elements not in the string.
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Fun without loops!

If there is punctuation you can use

```
preg_split('/^\w/', $my_string );
```

instead of `explode`

Comment: @Hobbes - Thanks.  Others have similar suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways I can think of. This first way is great, if you know for sure you'll always be able to split be a given character(s). It's short, sweet, and simple. Making use of [`array_dif`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and a simple [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
function isArrayInString($str, $ara, $splitter=" ") {
    $ret = array_diff($ara, explode($splitter, $str));
    return empty($ret);
}
```

**However**, that doesn't seem very dynamic and limits you based on "splitting" the string. An easier, possibly better way, would be to loop through your array and ensure every value of the array exist in the string by using [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
function isArrayInString($str, $ara, $splitter=" ") {
    foreach($ara as $v) if (strpos($str , $v) === false) return FALSE;
    return $TRUE;
}
```

---

### So something like:

```
$myArray = array("big", "blue", "sky", "dog"); 
$myString = "my big dog loves the blue sky"; 
echo isArrayInString($myString, $myArray);
```

Will output `TRUE`

### While something like:

```
$myArray = array("big", "blue", "sky", "dog"); 
$myString = "the big blue sky";
echo isArrayInString($myString, $myArray);
```

Will output `FALSE`

Comment: The big advantage from the second example is when punctuation is used.  Just thought I would point that out, however strpos may find partial string matches. Such as dog in dogs, which may or may not be the intended result.

Comment: I realize that that was why i deleted that comment a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $my_array = array("big", "blue", "sky", "dog"); 
    $my_string = "my big dog loves the blue sky"; 

    $result = 0;

    foreach($my_array as $value) {
        if (strpos($my_string, $value) !== false) 
            $result+=1; 
    }

    if($result == count($my_array))
        echo "true";
    else
        echo "false";

?>
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: strpos will find partial matches so is "my big dog loves the blue sky" the same as "mybigdoglovesthebluesky" or are we looking for words.  Is "dog" the same as "dogs"

Answer (score 0):

```
function allInString($str, $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
       if (strpos($str, $a) === false) {
           return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it would help if you also explain what you are doing more than just copy and paste some code

Answer (score -1):

```
$my_array = array("big", "blue", "sky", "dog");
$my_string = "my big dog loves the blue sky";
$inArray = true;

foreach($my_array as $field)
{
    if(!strpos($my_string,$field))
    {echo "$field is not";
        return false;}
}
return true;
```

Comment: You can delete the `$inArray = true;` line. It does nothing.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right - I am an old man and back in day - it was wise to be complete - old habits.   Good call though.

Comment: @terary I would leave it, even in today's 'day' you can get undefined variable errors, never hurts to set a default.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix but it's not even used anywhere else in the code but here. It does absolutely nothing.